# CSS FADE TRANSITION

Tags: html, css

I currently have the following code which fades in the header. I want the header to stay for about 3 seconds, then fadeout, automatically loading the main page of the website. It seems its quite difficult to do that. Can anyone help?

```
.fade1 {
    margin-top: 25px;
    font-size: 21px;
    text-align: center;

    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
       -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox < 16 */
        -ms-animation: fadein 2s; /* Internet Explorer */
         -o-animation: fadein 2s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
            animation: fadein 2s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this...The animation duration should be **7 seconds**

It fades in over 2 secs, stays for 3 seconds and then fades out over 2 seconds

```
 @keyframes fadein {
        0% { opacity: 0; }
        29% { opacity: 1; }
        72% {opacity:1;}
        100% {opacity:0;}
    }
```

[**JSfiddle Demo (Chrome)**](http://jsfiddle.net/u97puwf4/3/)

Comment: Thanks! But how would I make it automatically change to the main page after fading out?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're getting at...isn't the header on the main page? Either way, you'll need javascript.

Comment: no. the header is on its own in one page. when it fades out, i want it to automatically display another html page, sort of like a transition to another page

Comment: Then you definitely need Js.